# group column records python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, group-by

I have a column with the following records when taking out the .value_counts ().  This is a fragment of the column of my df

```
Mayo            76363
Marzo           74580
Abril           71219
Enero           70222
Junio           69692
Febrero         68943
May                30
Aabril             12
ENRO                4
Febrero-2015        1
Mayo-2018           1
```

I would only like to have the following values when taking out the .value_counts ()

```
enero       70226
febrero     68944
marzo       74580
abril       71231
mayo        76394
```

any idea how i could do it?

Thank you

Comment: after you get this result then store it in a variable for example `count=df['column'].value_counts()`....Now `count=count[count.index.isin(['Enero','Ebrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo'])]`

Comment: @Anurag the problem is that I am not adding all the values ​​for each month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to normalize month names before calling `df.value_counts()`, so that they grouped normally. We can fix it here by creating a replacement dictionary with proper names.

From the fragment you shown, you need to bring month names to proper format, so, assuming column names are `month` and `value`

```
# Name the columns
>>> df.columns = ["month", "value"]

# Get rid of `-` part, bring month names to lower case.
>>> df["month"] = df.month.str.split("-").str[0].str.lower()
>>> df
      month  value
0      mayo  76363
1     marzo  74580
2     abril  71219
3     enero  70222
4     junio  69692
5   febrero  68943
6       may     30
7    aabril     12
8      enro      4
9   febrero      1
10     mayo      1

# Get the dictionary of column names
>>> month_names = { i:i for i in df["month"].unique() }

# Update the month names which have error
>>> month_names["aabril"] = "abril"
>>> month_names["enro"]   = "enero"
>>> month_names["may"]    = "mayo"
>>> month_names
{'mayo': 'mayo', 'marzo': 'marzo', 'abril': 'abril', 'enero': 'enero', 'junio': 'junio', 'febrero': 'febrero', 'may': 'may', 'aabril': 'abril', 'enro': 'enero'}

# Rename the month column values
>>> df["month"] = df["month"].map(month_names)

# Now, group by month names
    >>> df.groupby("month").sum().reset_index()
     month  value
0    abril  71231
1    enero  70226
2  febrero  68944
3    junio  69692
4    marzo  74580
5     mayo  76394
```